Vs-code unable to import modules modules load
I'm opening the same python project in pycharm and everything is working well
opening same folder on vs code with same interpreter
I'm getting error 'Unable to import' on local modules in the project
what do i miss
Example tree
MyFile.py
│
├── csv (standard library)
├── io (standard library)
├── re (standard library)
│
|--  __init__.py
|
├── myproject.myfolder.mymodule
│   ├── methodA
│   ├── methodB
|   └-- __init__.py

MyFile.py
import csv
import io
import re

from myproject.myfolder.mymodule import methodA, methodB

in pycharm it working well, in Vs-code getting unable to import exception.
Note - i tried to create workspace and venv, not working either
Thanks in advance

The problem is with PYTHONPATH. Seems like in Pycharm it configured properly, but in VSCode it isn't.
You could configure PYTHONPATH manually:
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/myproject.myfolder.mymodule"

Or set it in .vscode/settings.json (create this folder and file if not created):
{
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "./",  // Path to root of project
    "/path/to/your/myproject.myfolder.mymodule
  ],
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "./",
    "/path/to/your/myproject.myfolder.mymodule"
  ]
}


Tried to add "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
"${workspaceFolder}/src/MyProject",  // Path to root of project
"${workspaceFolder}/src/MyProject/ai/chat"
and the same to python.analysis.extraPaths
still no luck, what do i miss?

Reload has changed it . working thank you very much !!!


Are methodA and methodB python files? In that case you would have to do
from myproject.myfolder.mymodule import methodA 
from myproject.myfolder.mymodule import methodB

Also make sure you run your program from the same directory as your myfile.py

No they are methods under mymodule directory which stated on the init.py of the module

You need to add init.py in the folders where you have your modules
└── src                <- Source code for use in this project.
    ├── __init__.py        <- Makes src a Python module.
    │
    ├── main.py            <- main python script
    │
    ├── \modeling
    │   ├── __init__.py    <- Makes modeling a Python module.   
    │   ├── predict.py     <- Code to run model inference with trained models.
    │   └── train.py       <- Code to train models.
    │
    ├── \utility           <- Scripts that serves as modules to import to make workflow more efficient.
    │   ├── __init__.py    <- Makes utility a Python module.
    │   ├── plots_cfg.py   <- Code to store plotting configuration.
    │   └── config.py      <- Code to store useful variables and configuration.

main.py
from utility import config
from modeling import predict


Thank you. i forgot to mention i do have init.py for all modules and root, and it works on pyCharm

Ensure the import paths in your code are correct. Sometimes relative imports can cause issues across IDEs. You may try replacing:
from myproject.myfolder.mymodule import methodA, methodB

with:
from .myfolder.mymodule import methodA, methodB

